# Can I use the "ll" contraction with proper names?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions, proper-nouns

Can I contract "will" as "ll" when preceded by a proper name? For example:

> John will visit you tomorrow
>
> John'll visit you tomorrow

I am inclined to think this is not acceptable in standard English. It's also not pretty when spoken. In which case, is this construction valid in any dialect?

Why am I asking this? (some people seem to care): I'm translating a game I originally wrote in Japanese, into English. I have a native English speaker taking care of the dialogue, and a construction similar to the one I wrote above appeared on the text he sent me to check.

I'm not a native English speaker, so even though I have probably heard that contraction a handful of times in my life, I would like to know if it is correct English.

It also happens that my native English speaker is from Texas, so it occurred to me that this is probably common in the Texan dialect of English. I have never been to Texas, so I have no idea if this is right.

Comment: Written? Spoken? Reported dialogue?

Comment: @tchrist: mostly spoken, but I'm also interested in the written form. Just like with other contractions, I'm sure it's more likely to come out in dialogue than in written English. In fact, I read something like that on a book, so I want to know if it is trying to imply a specific dialect/level of education, or if it is just plain wrong.

Comment: Do you by any chance still remember the name of that book? Or can you perhaps even cite the corresponding passage? Also, I am certain you don't really wish to imply that something that is a common feature of dialogue between native speakers can be "plain wrong", and hopefully neither does the book, but that's what you end up saying right now, and that of course doesn't compute. Thank you.

Comment: [General Reference](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22John'll%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @RegDwighт: Okay, to be more precise, it's not a book, but the currently in-progress English translation of a game I originally wrote in Japanese. My native English translator came up with such a construction, and I would like to know if it is correct, or under which circumstances it would be correct, so I can know whether or not to ask him to revise that passage. I honestly have no idea why the context of the question is relevant to the grammar though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Most of the references there are not using the contraction. Are you trying to tell me that since some published books use that construction, it is automatically correct?

Comment: @ Panda Pajama: I have no idea what you mean by "correct". I agree **John'll** probably wasn't the best choice of proper name because it gets mixed up with *John II (king, pope, etc.)*. But you could easily change it to [Jane'll](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Jane'll%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Nearly all of *those* are contractions.

Comment: *John'll visit you tomorrow* seems fine to me for spoken English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: correct as in "it abides by the rules of the English language". For example, "vxxsaxcd" is not correct English, as it is plain gibberish, while "Good morning!" is a correct English phrase.

Comment: I'm not with you. Clearly native speakers use contractions all the time, as I just did there. Idiomatically, many of us would probably avoid writing **Reg's right** here, even though we might write **Panda's wrong**. But that's just because it's meaningless to contract the former (since it would *sound* identical to the "non-contracted" version). You could consult a relevant style guide to establish whether certain contractions are "acceptable" in certain *written* contexts, but that's got very little to do with most English usage, which is primarily *spoken*.

Comment: Yes, that contraction is just fine for informal English. Contractions in general are considered bad form in formal written English, but are used unnoticeably in speech. This particular contraction sounds a little more informal, but is also probably not noticed in speech.

Comment: If this English-translated version of the game is to be used also by those whose native language is not English, then maybe avoid *John'll* and write *John will*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: yes. It'll be understood, and if it's seen as a mistake, it'd be one of *register* rather than of grammar.

Longer answer: contractions are informal by nature, so if you're asking about formal written English, then *any* contraction is frowned upon, whether it's "it's", "you're", or "John'll".

So we're clearly talking about less-than-formal English, where the rules (such as they are) get fuzzy.

- In spoken English, contractions are totally fair game. In fact, you really have to pay attention to even *notice* whether someone said "I am" or "I'm". The difference between "John will" and "John'll" is a bit more audible, but it's still perfectly fine to say the latter rather than the former.
- In written English, the contractions you choose to use, or not use, determine the level of informality. In this sense, "John'll" is a bit more informal than "you're", but there are very few contexts where the latter would be acceptable while the former wouldn't be.

Bottom line is, in an informal context such as a video game, usage such as "John'll" simply adds to the colloquial, informal nature of the dialogue/narration. It is not, in and of itself, a mistake.

Comment: I find it interesting that the contraction persists in spoken English even when the pronunciation is awkward. *Jill'll be at the conference Tuesday while Charles's presenting, but Jane and Peter're coming Wednesday.*

Comment: @choster: I dunno. I don't think saying "Jill'll" is any more awkward than saying "Jill will".

Comment: Michael'll seems to present more problems. John'll, Peter're, Bill'll etc are pronounced with a schwa. Michael already has one.

Comment: Unless you are an "acknowledged authority" on "standard English" (some like that myth to persist, you see), this makes no sense to any English speaker.

Comment: @Kris: could you please point out where I said anything about "standard English"?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for dialogue in a video game, then why would it matter if it's formally correct?

What are you striving for? To mimic the way the characters would actually communicate? Or to write a script that would pass for formal prose?

Authors such as Mark Twain, Stephen King, and Harper Lee often used constructs like this to add a sense of realism to the dialogue in their books, knowing that people often speak in a less formal way than they might write polished text.

> “Let him alone,” said Stuart Mordaunt. “His brother's absence has upset him, but Jim'll come round all right.” (*Mr. Groby's Slippery Gift* by Paul Laurence Dunbar)
>
> “I think that cat'll outlive us all,” I said and patted Tim on the shoulder. (*Night and the Cat* by Alan Adler)

By striking such contractions from the video game, you run the risk of having language that might sound artificial and contrived.

---

Incidentally, this is **why** you were asked about where you would use this, and why “people seemed to care.” If you were presenting at an academic conference, I think it would be a *terrible* idea to write `Dave'll go next` on one of your presentation slides. But that doesn't mean such informal phrasing should be removed from a video game dialogue. The theives in *Grand Theft Auto* don't generally speak like English gentlemen.

When you don't provide adequate context, the community cannot provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I asked whether or not it was _gramatically_ correct, not _formally_ correct. I still believe the context is irrelevant for a grammar question.

Comment: @PandaPajama: Define _grammatically correct._ I don't think "grammatically correct" is a box with fixed surfaces, but an elastic bag that stretches according to context. Who am I to tell Dunbar he should fix his sentence? Also, you could change my "Why would it matter if it's formally correct?" question to, "Why would it matter if it's grammatically correct?" and my answer would stay the same – unless you're merely curious, and not concerned at all with what goes in the final version of the video game. Lastly, you **didn't** ask if it was "grammatically correct," you asked, "Can I use it?"

Comment: I tagged it as "grammar", which is enough to note this is a grammar, not a register question. "Grammatically correct" means that "it abides by the rules of the English language". For example, a sentence such as "Clock it'd when pierce" is grammatically incorrect, while "My name is Panda" is grammatically correct. And it does matter a lot, because a poorly constructed translation would reflect lack of attention to detail and general lack of education, and could probably hurt the sales of my product.

Comment: @PandaPajama, actually "Clock it'd when pierce" is (or might be) grammatically fine. Where it runs into trouble is *semantics*. And the problem with "the rules of the English language" is not "rules" or "English", but that first "the".

Comment: Even though the English language does not have a central governing body who's there to say what is correct and what is not, I am pretty sure there are things I can write with my keyboard that are not correct English. The line between correct and incorrect is certainly blurry, but if I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to tell me that the English grammar is whatever anybody wants it to be. If that's the case, then what's the point of learning it?

Comment: I didn't say English is whatever anybody wants, but I will say that "Is this grammatically correct?" is a loaded question, and asking "Can I _use_ this?" with a grammar tag only makes it even more murky. In a dialog, what's inside the quotes reflects what the person _said_, and people often say things that don't follow strict English syntax. _Can_ you contract it? Of course you can! I gave two examples from literature, and there are plenty more. What makes you think you can't? If you're asking about grammar, though, ask about grammar, don't rely on a tag to ask the hard part of the question.

Comment: You can't usefully separate register from grammaticality, because different registers sometimes have different grammars.

Answer (score -1):

As a native English speaker, "John'll....." Is totally acceptable and not at all awkward to say.  In a sentence where I wish to stress that John is definitely going to do something, without any doubt, then I will say "John WILL..."....otherwise I'll contract it.  In natural connected speech, the "will" serving as helping verb will get reduced, and the resulting utterance is "'ll".  This pronunciation poses a problem for non-native English speakers where the "dark L" is non-existent in their native language, but can be learned.