# Contraction in "Your file'll be downloaded..."

Tags: contractions

Is it correct to use the contraction in *Your file'll be downloaded...*? I don't know. It just doesn't sound right to me. English is not my first language, so maybe someone here could shed some light on this issue.

Comment: This question would be better suited to our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "file'll" is understandable if spoken but it's not really good written English.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113980

Comment: It wouldn't even be spoken; it's not a valid contraction. Contractions are to save phonetic effort, and two L's in a row is more difficult to pronounce instead of easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct is an awkward one, due to the absent (contracted out) vowel, but entirely legal.

Native English speakers know to insert a schwa in place of the absent vowel when speaking.

As noted elsewhere, though grammatical this particular contraction should perhaps be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

It's an acceptable contraction as it makes grammatical sense.

However, given the assumed context (a message on a website?), I would personally avoid it and go with "Your file will...".