# Is "all'l" a suitable contraction?

Tags: contractions

I was wondering, can I contract "all" and "will" into "all'l"? Is it generally accepted, or is it more of an obscure contraction?

Comment: Could you give us an example sentence in which it is used? Out of context, it is hard to say.

Comment: As in *all will be well/all'll be well*? I can imagine it in casual speech, but I've never seen it in print. I think it would be fine in dialogue, borderline in casual correspondence (including social media, email, etc.), and probably a bad idea in narration or anything more formal.

Comment: I'll echo 1006a and say that if you're going to use this, you should spell it with two l's, not one: "all'll".

Comment: I suppose one might say "Whether they be Republican or Democrat, all'll be welcome to our meeting."  But it's not a common contraction.

Comment: Why *all'l*? Try *all'll.* The latter is fine as a representation of speech or in informal writing. And yes it is rare. People might prefer to say *they'll all* or *we'll all*.

Comment: In my experience *all'll* occurs in speech, but not generally in writing. For example, I have heard *y'all'll* used in casual speech more times than I could count, but the more accepted way to say or write that contraction would probably be *you'll all*, which fits with what Clare said.

Comment: It's suitable to pronounce it that way in informal speech, and "all'll" will probably be better understood as representing the informal speech in writing, but it is not a recognized contraction like "don't" or "could've" (the latter is barely recognized formally)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contraction *'ll*, which is short for *will*, in a wide [variety](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113984/191178) of situations. It has two L's after the apostrophe; any other number of L's will be wrong.

Of course, it may not give the impression you want, since it's informal and mostly used verbally. In writing, it's often used to [emulate](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/writing-accents-and-dialects) certain accents or dialects.

It's a bit hard to find examples, but I did find [some](https://www.google.com/#q=%22all%27ll+be%22+-%22y%27all%27ll%22):

> She'll get over the mad when she finds there's no one to be mad with, so all'll be right.
>   <sub>[Alnomuc, Or, The Golden Rule: With Twenty-four Engravings](https://books.google.com/books?id=JmsCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA14), 1837</sub>

> It'll fair off tomorrow and the sun'll be out again, and Mr. Hardy'll be back and all'll be fine.
>   <sub>[American Plays](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ioOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22all%27ll+be%22), 1935</sub>

> All'll be right then. He and his wife'll welcome you there, especially when there're little 'uns.
>   <sub>[An Unlikely Countess](https://books.google.com/books?id=2WwAfFlIrTEC&pg=PT30), 2012</sub>

It's also worth noting that the contraction [*y'all'll*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Y%27all%27ll) is used in the Southern US. In some instances, *You all'll* is used.

Answer (score 0):

No, this would not be a generally accepted contraction. Perhaps it would be used upon occasion to capture slurred speech, but I've never seen it.  Unfortunately, the corpora that I checked don't allow searching for contractions, but a Google search for "all'll" brings up few hits.

Comment: When the hostess in the Atlanta restaurant says, "Y'all'll need a reservation tonight", only the New Yorkers (ironically) think it's "slurred speech".