# Can the contracted form of "will" be used after "and"?

Tags: contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

Is it correct to write:

> hope you enjoyed the demo and'll consider the idea

Or I must all the way use the entire word for "will" in that phrase?

Thank you in advance for clarifications

Comment: *And'll* can be used used and understood in informal writing or speech. In formal writing, the spelled out version would be used.

Comment: I would say that in speech this happens fairly frequently, especially when speaking quickly.  In writing, however, it just looks bizarre, and even in informal writing I would never use it. (Unless of course I was writing dialogue.)

Comment: How about "but'll", or "then'll". "The meeting was arranged for Tuesday, but'll now be Friday". Or "Sam will sing a song, then'll go home". Or possibly "now'll", "The pickers who did get five quid a sack, now'll get six".

Comment: Or even Fred'll. "Fred'll now sing a song".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [Can I use the “ll” contraction with proper names?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113980/can-i-use-the-ll-contraction-with-proper-names)

This is the first part of the top answer as written by Marthaª:

> Short answer: yes. It'll be understood, and if it's seen as a mistake, it'd be one of register rather than of grammar.

Let's build on that, because while it's only answering the question for proper names, a similar explanation applies even to *and*.

Yes, as a contraction of "will," *'ll* can be added to pronouns, proper nouns, and any other word plausibly followed by *will* where the /wɪ/ sound can be [elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) in spoken language. In standard lists pronominal forms dominate because they are the ones used most often (I'll, you'll, she'll, and so on), but other formations are possible. (Dan'll show up, the priest'll arrive.) You found a situation where *will* follows *and* and can be contracted. Congratulations!

Now, should you write it? Consider these factors:

1. Register. How formal or informal is your context? Lots of people will say that contractions are only appropriate in formal writing, like [this APA Style Blog author](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/12/contractions-in-formal-writing-whats-allowed-whats-not.html). This is true for more usual contractions, so it'd also be true for less usual ones. It sounds more colloquial and more spoken in writing, and so should be used only when you want to sound that way.
2. Frequency. More frequent contractions will be more readily understood and accepted by readers. In contrast, a rarer contraction like *and'll* will draw attention because of how unusual it is. Know your reader. If your audience is a professor or someone in authority, using *and'll* is a huge risk unless you know they're okay with unconventional writing.
3. Context. Obviously if you're trying to write dialogue or present recorded speech, the contraction may be appropriate. If you're cultivating an email style where your writing is impeccable and sometimes has a spoken quality, this may offer the touch you want.

In short, this is grammatically okay but stylistically carries risks that you should consider.

Comment: If you find another post that seems to provide the needed answer, call it a "Possible Duplicate" or "Related". Do not reproduce in toto to make your own answer.

Comment: It didn't provide the needed answer. It provided an answer to a different case, I cited the small part that was relevant, and I did not reproduce it *in toto*. "And" is not a proper name.

Comment: @Kris I agree with TaliesinMerlin: the case here is about using it with the "and" conjunction, not a proper name so it's a different "affair".  TaliesinMerlin , thank you for your answer